# Why is my function not recognizing my global variables? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, global-variables

My issue is in the `script` element at the bottom of the `body`. The function works fine when you declare the `pageTop`, `menu` and `yPos` variables inside the `yScroll` function but not when it's outside. If they are outside the function and are global variables, shouldn't my `function` still be able to use them? I don't understand why it doesn't work when I try to define the variables outside the function.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #pagetop {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 120px;
            background: #06C;
            color: #FFF;
            font-size: 23px;
            padding-top: 50px;
            transition: height 0.3s linear 0s, padding 0.3s linear 0s;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #pagetop > #menu {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #004A95;
            height: 50px;
            transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
        }

        #wrapper {
            margin-top: 230px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pagetop">
        Header
        <div id="menu">Menu system</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <script>
            for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
            document.write("<h2>dummy page content</h2>")
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <script>

        var pagetop = document.getElementById('pagetop');
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        var yPos = window.pageYOffset;

        window.addEventListener('scroll', yScroll);

        function yScroll() {
            if (yPos > 150) {
                pagetop.style.height = '36px';
                pagetop.style.paddingTop = '8px';
                menu.style.height = '0px';
            }
            else {
                pagetop.style.height = '120px';
                pagetop.style.paddingTop = '50px';
                menu.style.height = '50px';
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it was something with the yPos variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine, except that **`yPos` is only set once at page load** and will always stay `0`.

To resolve this, read the scroll position each time the event handler is called, inside your `yScroll` function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #pagetop {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 120px;
      background: #06C;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 23px;
      padding-top: 50px;
      transition: height 0.3s linear 0s, padding 0.3s linear 0s;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #pagetop > #menu {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #004A95;
      height: 50px;
      transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
    }
    #wrapper {
      margin-top: 230px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pagetop">
    Header
    <div id="menu">Menu system</div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <script>
      for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        document.write("<h2>dummy page content</h2>")
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <script>
    var pagetop = document.getElementById('pagetop');
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', yScroll);

    function yScroll() {
      var yPos = window.pageYOffset;

      if (yPos > 150) {
        pagetop.style.height = '36px';
        pagetop.style.paddingTop = '8px';
        menu.style.height = '0px';
      } else {

        pagetop.style.height = '120px';
        pagetop.style.paddingTop = '50px';
        menu.style.height = '50px';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

snippet works: (http://codepen.io/f7o/pen/JKWKgb)

`yPos` variable is only set on document load, and never again on scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Your function *is* recognising the global variables, the issue is the are only only set once. What you're basically doing by initialising `yPos` outside the function scope with:

`var yPos = window.pageYOffset`

is

`var yPos = 0`

This will never change, because you are not reassigning the value. Because yPos should be dynamic, this needs to be moved into the scope (in fact, it doesn't even need to be declared). The other variables are fine outside, because they don't change.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3p3rvvs/1/)